# Android : Accessing container activity object from fragment using putExtra?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tabs

I am building a tab interface using Action bar and fragment. I would need assistance in sending data from container activity to the fragment.

To elaborate, I have job object in container activty. And I have created few tabs based on the information in job object (like company details, experience details etc). I need to pass the job object to these fragments so that it can display respective information.

I have created container activity and tab fragments. I would need an example on how to pass the object across them. I cannot use intent.putExtra. Can I access parent container's object from fragment?

Any help shall be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have You checked http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html ?

Comment: @sandrstar included the link you also posted in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how can fragment take a global variable of Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364434/android-how-can-fragment-take-a-global-variable-of-activity)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make the method in your activity, e.g `getJob` that will return the `Job` object and its information

```
MyActivity extends Activity{
Job mJob;

public Job getJob(){
   return this.mJob;
 }
}
```

then in your Fragment you do this:

```
MyFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(){
  super.onActivityCreated();
  ((MyActivity)this.getActivity()).getJob();
 }
}
```

use `getActivity` and the method `getJob();` to get the object

Comment: Many Thanks. I am able to access the object using getActivity().

Comment: @Maid786 post your code. I assume that you add fragment to more than ona activity. And then you typecast parent activity to wrong type. Make all your activities iplement some interface ex. IParentActivity  and typecast your getActivity result to it

Comment: It returns a single object. How should I implement this for multiple objects?

Comment: @Machado Just change return type to Bundle or List<?>

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

1. Make a `static` variable to hold your data and access that data from inside the fragments - this is the most fast but it creates bad design patterns if used improperly.
2. A way of `Fragment-to-Fragment communication possible through the parent Activity` is posted here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html You can use the sample code to just do a `Activity - Fragment data send`.
3. The top voted answer here: [Accessing instance of the parent activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944651/accessing-instance-of-the-parent-activity) mentions `a way to avoid using static data` (1.) and contains source code examples using `ActivityGroup`

> "If you need access to some values in your First activity without
>   making a static reference to it, you could consider putting your
>   activities in an ActivityGroup."

What you choose is your preference, these are just a few options!

---

Edit: I'm not sure if number 3 will work with fragments since I haven't tested a method similar to it, the example is Activity - Activity communication.

Comment: Thanks. I am using alternative suggested by Greensy. If I am stuck, I would try your suggestion.