# Xamarin Android knowing parent Activity so to send result to the correct opener?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I have an Activity (C) which can be opened (for result) from more than one other Activity (A and B).
Sometimes it goes [A -> B -> C] and sometimes it just goes [A -> C].

I want the scenario [A -> B -> C] to make C return the result to B.

And I want scenario [A -> C] to make C return the result to A.

In both cases Activity C is supposed to do the same thing, but how do I know which Activity type I should use for my Intent when preparing the result (aka how do I know which Activity opened C)?

This os probably rather trivial but I'm a Xamarin noob so bear with me.

/Aidal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing instance of the parent activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944651/accessing-instance-of-the-parent-activity)

Comment: Not completely since the other post only has 2 avtivities, but none the less I got pointed in the right direction by it. It seem that this will do the trick: this.CallingActivity.ClassName.Split('.')[1] = <opening activity class name>. Thanks!

Comment: You can add extra data to your Intent and access it in the "child" Activity.: `intent.PutExtra(....);` and react to it accordingly to avoid hardcoding ClassName checks in the "child" Activity to avoid the "code smell".

Comment: Of cause, I dunno why I didn't think of that because I already use that feature to pass data :D

Comment: In Android (native) you would use `startActivityForResult()`. It looks like Xamarin supports this as well. See https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_activity_for_result/